# Power BI custom visual image hyperlink does not work

Tags: d3.js, powerbi

I am creating a simple power BI custom visual , which will have an image which when clicked will open the link in new browser window/tab. I have followind code in the constructor of visual.ts:-

```
constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {

    this.svgRoot = d3.select(options.element).append("svg");            

    this.rectElement = this.svgRoot.append('svg:a')
                        .attr('xlink:href', 'https://someurl')
                        .attr('target', '_blank')                            
                        .append('svg:image')
                        .attr('xlink:href' , 'http://imageurl')                            

}
```

I have tried following for target attribute:-

1. with no "target" attribute, the link opens in the same frame as the visual in this case
2. with "target" set to _parent and _top I get error which says:- "The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set."
3. with "target" attribute set to _blank, nothing happens here when I click on image.

I want _blank to work so that the link opens in new tab or browser window, can this be achieved.